# SQLite3 ODBC driver - Access / Excel commas instead of dots

Tags: excel, sqlite, ms-access, odbc

I have a database in a file (SQLite3).
I create a connection using: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

I want to transfer some things to Access / Excel. The problem occurs when connected to the database. In SQLite, the decimal separator is a dot and a comma is used in my region. Therefore, numbers with decimal places are shown in cells as text. How to solve it?
In the system it has to stay as it is (commas).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could use :-

```
SELECT replace(the_column,'.',',') AS the_column FROM the_table;
```

## Example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS the_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the_table (the_column);
INSERT INTO the_table VALUES('100.450'),('200.560'),('300.670');
SELECT replace(the_column,'.',',') AS the_column FROM the_table;
```

## Result :-

[image]

Comment: There will be a technical problem with this.
I have about 500 columns in all tables!

There is no system solution?

The point is that Access or Excel should see these dots as commas. It's not possible? The SQLite database is ok, numbers are numbers.

Comment: @Qlikeers probably but *System* is vague e.g The system could generate the SQL statements; The system could process the result set and execute whatever the system has for string replacement. Technically either way it's not really a problem unless you exceed limits, such as 1000000 being the default (can be adjusted) length of an SQL statement in SQLite.

Comment: I do not know if we understand each other.
I have data in the SQLite database that I can use. A lot of columns, including numbers with decimal places.

I am looking for a way that will allow me to export data from the database (ODBC driver) with numbers in which a decimal place is designated by a comma (not a dot, which is the default).

Comment: @Qlikeers If you look at the SQL the first 3 lines are creating mock data to demonstrate, it's the last line that is the export and the result shows period (as per mock data) converted to comma. i.e the result equates to the export and thus periods are changed to commas. Of course if it's the other way round then it's simply a matter of swapping the comma in single quotes to a period and vice-versa.

Comment: Maybe I try in different way - how to connect data from SQLite to Access (ODBC), to treat numbers as numbers. Because Access treats them as text (through these dots in decimal places).

Numbers in the SQL database have dots by default as decimal places, right?
I work in Europe, where commas are standard - not dots.

When I try to connect data from the SQLite database to Excel or Access, they get with dots and automatically converted to text (should be the number).

Comment: Access should treat numbers as numbers. So, it will depend on the ODBC driver, and how the columns were defined in SQLite.  I find  that number columns come over just fine as numbers.

Comment: But Access / Excel treats as text, so what else can I do?